# Can I throw exceptions through functions compiled w/o exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

Let we have two libraries: `libA.a` and `libB.a`. They are organised s.t. `libA.a` calls `libB.a` functions and provides a callback to itself. In other words, the following call stack is possible:

```
#0 liba_callback()
#1 libb_function()
#2 liba_function()
```

`libA.a` is compiled with `-fexceptions` and `libB.a` is compiled with `-fno-exceptions`.

The question is: what happens if `liba_callback()` throws? Can I handle this in `liba_function()`? Can I throw exceptions through functions compiled w/o exceptions? Is this behaviour defined?

Comment: Sidestepping the question a little bit: Even if you would be able to you shouldn't because of allocated ressources. Given libB is not supporting exceptions, it won't handle them gracefully, not calling cleanup code and thus leaking ressources.

Comment: The behavior is not defined by the C++ standard. Exceptions are part of the language, so a compiler that doesn't support exceptions (-fno-exceptions) does not conform to the language definition. There might be some documentation for the compiler that explains what happens in a case like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pete Becker noted, exceptions are part of the language, so the compiler is responsible for documenting such C++ dialect.

The [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_exceptions.html) says:

> Before detailing the library support for -fno-exceptions, first a passing note on the things lost when this flag is used: it will break exceptions trying to pass through code compiled with -fno-exceptions whether or not that code has any try or catch constructs. If you might have some code that throws, you shouldn't use -fno-exceptions. If you have some code that uses try or catch, you shouldn't use -fno-exceptions.

In particular, hitting a stack frame with no unwind information is problematic:

> In particular, unwinding into a frame with no exception handling data will cause a runtime abort. If the unwinder runs out of unwind info before it finds a handler, std::terminate() is called.

---

**To sum up:**

> The question is: what happens if liba_callback() throws?

`abort()` is called.

> Can I handle this in liba_function()?

No.

> Can I throw exceptions through functions compiled w/o exceptions?

No.

> Is this behaviour defined?

No. It is only documented as a compiler extension.